# iOS BackgroundFetch equivalent in Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I would like to know if there is an Android counterpart for iOS `BackgroundFetch` feature.

I would like my Android app using Cordova to wake up every 15 minutes or so and check for updates and perform some other miscellaneous tasks.

In iOS, I was able to do this by using [cordova-background-fetch](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-fetch) plugin.

Since there is no Android version of that plugin, I am happy to write it myself; but I would first like to know how I would go about implementing such feature in Android. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you can set `AlarmManger` to wakes up every X milliseconds and run a `PendingIntent`.

This code looks something like this.

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                    PERIOD,
                    pi);
```

Android's default `IntentService`  that runs in the background has some limitations.

You can also take a look at external libary `WakefulIntentService` (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).  I use that along with `AlarmManager` to run background tasks.

**Updated**:

OnAlarmReceiver class

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String TAG = "OnAlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Waking up alarm");
        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, YourService.class); // do work in the service class
    }

}
```

YourService class

```
public class YourService extends WakefulIntentService {

      public static String TAG = "YourService";

      public YourService() {
          super("YourService");
      }

      @Override
      protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Waking up service");

        // do your background task here
      }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good starting point. I implemented `OnAlarmReceiver` class by extending `BroadcastReceiver`. Do I need to call `registerReceiver` somewhere to listen to the intent that is broadcast in the third line? Couldn't find `registerReceiver` in `WakefulIntentService`'s codebase, and I am confused.

Comment: @MikeC I updated answer with complete example. You will also have to define your service and receiver in Manifest file to make it work.

Comment: I did not end up using `WakefulIntentService`, but thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: btw, how do you clear the intents you set by `AlarmManager #setRepeating` when the app terminates? I am happy to post a separate question if answer is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Besides that you can also use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).